# Issue with TextView in ConstrainLayout

Tags: java, android, textview, constraints

Thank for reading................

i have 3 textviews : tag1, tag_separator, tag2.
And tag_separator's text is always : " / ".

what i want is 3 textviews will display as bellow rule:

[image]

**follow above display rule,i think tag1 and tag2 must be wrap_content but when in case that one of them's text is too long, the other will be move to outside of their parent bound.
How can i fix it??**

**note:** tried add"android:constrainWidth="true" but not work in this case.
my xml code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_width_la"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_height_la"
    android:background="@drawable/right_dialog_keys_vector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hom_046"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_content_margin_left_la"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_title_margin_top"
        style="@style/text_48.a100_white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag_height"
        style="@style/text_72.blue.a100"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_content_margin_left_la"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag1_margin_top"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="BAAAADDDDDDDDDasdasdDDDasdaqwDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tag_separator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag_height"
        style="@style/text_72.blue.a100"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag1_margin_top"
        android:text=" / "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tag_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tag_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag_height"
        style="@style/text_72.blue.a100"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_content_margin_right_la"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/youtube_link_keyword_dialog_tag1_margin_top"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:text="BASASASASASasdasdasasdasdasdddSAS"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tag_separator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

anyone can help please. thank you for reading!!!!!

Comment: Describe your question better please

Comment: sorry for my bad describe. my problem is in case that text of tag1 TextView ( or tag2 TextView) is too long.then the other will move to outside of parent bound. how can i fix it?

Comment: i searched some theard which related to my problem and their solution maybe is add "android:constrainWidth="true"  to prevent of over the parent bounds. but it not work in my case.